# In jQuery, how to call a `function` that works on load event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using [Supersized jQuery plugin](http://www.buildinternet.com/project/supersized/).

This plugin is used to make full screen background slides.

It works very fine when I want to call it on document load:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.supersized({
        slides  :  [
           { image :'sh490.jpg', title : 'title 1', url : '' },
           { image :'sh390.jpg', title : 'title 2', url : '' }
        ]
    });
});
```

What if I want to call `$.supersized({ .. });` (again or for the first time) with new params without reloading the page... For example after calling an Ajax function that returns "new images to be slided"..

Any tricks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in my comment you need to trigger the `load` event after setting new options. This is because the developer has bound the functionality to the event internally. You can trigger the event manually with `$(window).trigger('load')`. However this may have negative consequences because any other event handlers bound to this event are going to fire again as well so keep that in mind.

If I were you I would fork his code from github and modify it to use a custom event and then bind a function that triggers that custom event to window.load. This way you can trigger only that custom event from your click or loading function and have it triggered initially on `window.load`.

Or you could add a public destroy method that completely removes injected dom elements and event bindings the plugin has created before initializing it again with new parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Any tricks like sticking it in a function and calling it whenever you want, from wherever you want...?

```
var superSizeMe = function(p){
    $.supersized({ slides  : p });
};

$.getJSON("myfile.json", function(json){
    superSizeMe(json);
});
```

Comment: and it doesnt work as I want! When I try to call it... not whole the functionality of `$.supersized` get done as expected!

Answer (score 0):

I think you could perfectly call this plugin filled with a new set of images as a function like this:

```
mySlidesFunction(jsonSlides){
    $.supersized({slides  :  jsonSlides});
}
```

Comment: I want to call `$.supersized` on "click" function for example. but i want it to work as it works when called on load!

Comment: Have you tried to call mySlidesFunction(initialjsonImgSet); on load?

Comment: did you try `$(window).trigger('load')` after calling supersize again? Im not sure if that event even works with `trigger` but its worth a shot.

Comment: prodigitalson: this is what was missed! calling `$(window).trigger('load')`!

Comment: @amrnt: see my answer for a more in depth response.